# Remove tabs from buddypress groups and members pages

Tags: buddypress

Basically if you see the picture below there are 5 tab items in my groups page:

[image: Screenshot]

Now, I want to be able to remove some of them. I want to be able to remove "Members" and "Send Invites" (for instance).

This is on the frontend groups page. When you select a group and go to view it.

I don't want to edit core files really, is there any other way to do this? Maybe a remove_action?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to crawl through the core code and find this function:

`bp_core_remove_subnav_item`

So you can do something like this:

```
function remove_group_options() {
    global $bp;

    bp_core_remove_subnav_item($bp->groups->slug, 'members');
    bp_core_remove_subnav_item($bp->groups->slug, 'send-invites');

}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'remove_group_options' );
```

Comment: this has no effect for me in BP 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

The answer above does not work in 1.5

```
$bp->groups->slug
```

needs to become

```
bp_get_current_group_slug()
```

To support both version of bp use:

```
function remove_group_options()
{
    global $bp;
    $parent_slug = isset( $bp->bp_options_nav[$bp->groups->current_group->slug] ) ? $bp->groups->current_group->slug : $bp->groups->slug;
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( $parent_slug, 'members' );
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( $parent_slug, 'send-invites' );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'remove_group_options' );
```

Comment: this causes page not found errors for me in BP 1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in BP 2.0.1:

The functions for removing the nav and subnav items are similar except that the subnav function requires an additional argument to specify the main nav, of which it is a sub-item.

Thus, the following code removes the main nav item "forums" and also removes the "change-avatar" subnav item from the main nav item "Profile":

```
function remove_nav_items() {
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'forums' );
    bp_core_remove_subnav_item( 'profile', 'change-avatar' );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'remove_nav_items');
```

I've tested this in the bp-default theme in BP 2.0.1 and also in my own site.

Hope it helps :-)